# python recursive decorator

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I have a function that returns a list of dictionaries from an API call. The API can return max 100 records per request. Records are stored in pages, each page containing 100 records.

```
def call_api(page):
    return list_of_records
```

what I need is a decorator that can re-run this function every time it returns 100 records with the page argument =+ 1.

something like:

```
if len(list_of_records) == 100:
   call_api(page +=1)
```

the final output should be one single list with all the records

Comment: are you ready to rerun your function if there's 10000000 records to hold it in one list?

Comment: I would put a limit on how many retries. The question is purely theoretical.

Comment: Does it have to be a decorator? IMHO it would make more sense to make this either a wrapper function (that does _not_ replace the original function) or an additional optional parameter like `call_api(page, max_pages=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a decorator that recursively calls a function is certainly possible.

Here is how such a decorator might look in your case:

```py
import functools

def with_pages(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)

    def wrapper(page):
        list_of_records = []
        partial_list = func(page)
        list_of_records.extend(partial_list)
        while len(partial_list) == 100:  # there is probably a better condition to check if you are at the last page (e.g. next_page URI in api reply)
            page += 1
            partial_list = func(page)
            list_of_records.extend(partial_list)
        return list_of_records
    return wrapper

@with_pages
def call_api(page):
    # api interaction creating list_of_records_on_a_page
    return list_of_records_on_a_page
```

---

Alternatively, you can adapt `call_api` such that you can call it recursively.

Something like:

```py
def call_api(page, list_of_records=[]):
    partial_list = ... # the records you get from the api
    list_of_records.extend(partial_list)
    # often api provide the url for the next page or some more reliable info
    # about whether or not you are on the last page, i.e. testing for the length
    # of the reply is probably not the best strategy
    if len(partial_list) == 100:
        # time.sleep(0.2)  # just to not end up with to many requests in a short period of time
        call_api(page + 1, list_of_records)
    return list_of_records
```

Simply calling `call_api(1)` will be enough to get all pages.

Comment: can this be turned to a decorator?

Comment: yes, if you it really has to be a decorator you can produce a similar behavior with a decorator. Will add it...

Comment: also, the current function returns: <class 'NoneType'>

Comment: you are right, my bad! the return should not be conditional - fixed it. Glad I could help!